# Why is there a space between a H3 and DIV

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, listbox

I have the following code in ASP.net which displays a header and a `ListBox`:

```
<div id="divEntMain">
    <div class="clsEntMain">
        <h3>Entities</h3>
        <div class="clsLBHolder">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbEnt" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS defines the look:

```
.clsEntMain h3
{
    background: #F06600;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#divEntMain
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#lbEnt
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

If I modify to this The `ListBox` moves up just a little bit but I don't want to as the spacing might change based on screen resolution.:

`<div style="margin-top: -5px;" class="clsLBHolder">`

Why is there a space between the orange `H3` and the `ListBox`?

Comment: Did you try to open the web debugger/inspector (F12 in most browsers) and inspect the page to see which control is taking the space? You can make live changes from the inspector too.

Comment: Most likely the default bottom margin value on the `<h3>` tag.

Comment: Didn't know about the margin... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default margin for `h3` is :

```
margin-before: 1em;
margin-after: 1em;
margin-start: 0;
margin-end: 0;
```

To override this, you could

```
h3{
   margin: 0;
}
```

More info about default properties for html elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h3.html